# Delphi построение графика

Tags: график, delphi

Имеется функция

```
procedure TForm1.vvp6Click(Sender: TObject);
var
n:Integer;

begin
for n:=0 to vvp7.ColCount-1 do
if(vvp7.Cells[n,0]='') then
vvpi:=n;

try

vvp5.Caption:=FloatToStr(StrToFloat(vvp1.Text)+StrToFloat(vvp2.Text)-StrToFloat(vvp3.Text)-StrToFloat(vvp4.Text));

vvp7.Cells[vvpi,0]:=IntToStr(StrToInt(vvp0.Text));

vvp7.Cells[vvpi,1]:=vvp5.Caption;
vvp8.Series[0].AddXY(0,0,'',clTeeColor); 
for n:=1 to vvp7.ColCount-1 do
vvp8.Series[0].AddXY(StrToInt(vvp7.Cells[n,0]),StrToFloat(vvp7.Cells[n,1]),'',clTeeColor);
vvp7.ColCount:=vvp7.ColCount+1;
except
Application.Title:='Ошибка';
ShowMessage('Введите цифры и заполните все поля корректно!');
end;
```

Все работает прекрасно, но график начинается с точки 0 0, что вполне понятно. если убрать строку с добавлением точки 0 0, выводится ошибка

> project raised exception class EAccessViolation with message ' Access violation at address 00401DF6 in module'

При чем если вместо 0 0 добавлять первую точку с любыми цифрами все так же прекрасно работает, в чем проблема подскажите?'

Comment: Думаю беда тут `vvp7.Cells[n,0]` - если точки нету то и Cells[0,0] нету

Comment: тогда почему добавляет значение после точки 0 0 ? указал значения вручную, та же самая ошибка. замечено что программа работает верно и без нулевой точки когда значения маленькие до 1000 где то